# GUI update in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface

[image]I'm working on a project which I need get some data(points) from a device and show them on the widget. I'm using Qt 5 and C++ language. the data come 12 times in a second and each time it has 895 points. actually its a simulation of PPI display of a Radar. I a have list which I put the point on that, and then I try to paint them on the widget. the problem is when I draw points on the widget it will connects the points and draw lines that obviously are unwanted.

```
void FormPPI::PPIUpdate()
{
QPainter* pdc = new QPainter();
ObservationList* list = monitoring->getObservationList();
ObservationList::iterator it = list->begin();

// qDebug() << list->size();
while (it != list->end())
{
    Observation *o = &(*it);

    int xp, yp;
    float angle = calcPhi(o->pos().bearing());
    //Find the pixel position on the screen
    getPixelPos(o->pos().range() * cos(angle * DEG2RAD),
                o->pos().range() * sin(angle * DEG2RAD),    xp, yp);

    //Draw observations here
    //o->lifeTime() gets object lifetime which is initialized by 12 
    //used to reduce the intensity of color like antique radar system displays
    pdc->fillRect(xp - 1, yp - 1, 2, 2, QColor(255, 255, 0, o->lifeTime() * 21));

    //Decrease the observation life time by 1
    o->decLifeTime();

    if(o->lifeTime() <= 1)
        list->erase(it);

    it++;
}
qDebug() << list->size();
update();
list->release();
```

}

Comment: Can you show pictures of desired output and effective output?

Comment: the desired output is simply a PPI display with some color points on that, I will add a picture to show what I got

Comment: This is not your actual code.  A `QPainter` must have a paint device set on it before it can paint, this code would generate a lot of warnings and do nothing.  It would also be helpful if you provided your paintEvent() method, since that's the part that actually paints to the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to explain why

```
pdc->fillRect(xp - 1, yp - 1, 2, 2, QColor(255, 255, 0, o->lifeTime() * 21));
```

fill rectanges between two consecutives point `(xp1,yp1)` and `(xp2,yp2)` .

But you have an alternative. You can draw points directly with a specific diameter `d` (seems you want a diameter of approximately `2 pixels`).

```
int diameter = 2;
QPen pen = pdc->pen();
pen.setWidth(2);
pdc.setPen(pen);

while()
{
   ... 
   pen.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 0, o->lifeTime() * 21));
   pdc->setPen(pen);
   pdc->drawPoint(xp, yp);
   ...
}
```